# Deep linking in Webview Android Studio mobile app

Tags: android, wordpress, android-studio, deep-linking

I'm currently making a Webview (wordpress) based mobile app with Android Studio. 
And i want to integrate deep linking (like branch metrics to redirect users to the app version (if they have) of any links on my website.. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Comment: Thank you i'm gonna try this today! ;)